# NoReverse match at

Tags: python, django

Cannot find out why my web app keeps throwing this error. I am clueless

```
NoReverseMatch at /new-orders/order-list/
Reverse for 'order-sent' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) 
tried: ['new\\-orders/order\\-list/(?P<order_id>[0-9]+)/sent/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/new-orders/order-list/
Django Version: 2.2.3
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value: Reverse for 'order-sent' with arguments '('',)' notfound. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['new\\-orders/order\\-list/(?P<order_id>[0-9]+)/sent/$']
Reverse for 'order-sent' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['new\\-orders/order\\-list/(?P<order_id>[0-9]+)/sent/$']
```

here is my views.py where I want to change the booleanField order_sent to True.

```
def sent(request, order_id):
    order = get_object_or_404(Order, pk=order_id)
    try:
       selected_order = order.objects.get(pk=request.POST['order'])
    except (KeyError, Order.DoesNotExist):
       return render(request, 'new_orders/order-list.html', {
           'order': order,
           'error_message': "You did not select a valid Order",})
    else:
        selected_order.order_sent = True
        selected_order.save()
    return render(request, 'new_orders/order-list.html', {'order': order})
```

here is my model.py:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='myuser')
    order_number = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique=True)
    order_sent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

here is urls.py

```
app_name = 'new_orders'

urlpatterns = [
    path("order-list/", views.index, name='order-list'),
    path("order-list/<int:order_id>/", views.detail, name='order-detail'),
    path("order-list/<int:order_id>/sent/", views.sent, name='order-sent'),
]
```

and my order-list.html:

```
<form action="{% url 'new_orders:order-sent' order.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
   <ul>
       {% for order in all_orders %}
        <li><a href="{{ order.id }}"> User: <b>{{ order.order_user }}</b> | Order Type : <b>{{ order.order_type }}</b> | Device: <b>{{ order.order_device }}</b> | Count: <b>{{ order.order_count }}</b> | Order Number: <b>{{ order.order_number }}</b> | Date: <b>{{ order.order_date }}</b> | <b>{{ order.order_buffer }}</b> | Note: <b>{{ order.order_note }}</b> | Order Sent: <b>{{ order.order_sent }}</b> </a>
        <input type="checkbox" id="order{{ forloop.counter }}" name="order" value="{{ order.id }}">
        <label for="order{{ forloop.counter }}">
            {% if order.order_sent %}
                <img src="https://imgur.com/a/zXKjvAj"/>
            {% endif %}
        </label>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</form>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

I want to change the order_sent from False state to True via form in the html. Any thoughts what is wrong? I am trying to implement something like this from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=irH98-4eKmQ&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBlmzzFcLgDhKTTfNLfX1IK&index=24).

Comment: Is `views.index` defined?

Comment: is defined as: def index(request):
    all_orders = Order.objects.all().order_by("-id")
    return render(request,'new_orders/order-list.html', {'all_orders': all_orders})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have `order` in context here

```
<form action="{% url 'new_orders:order-sent' order.id %}" method="post">
```

You can reference to `order` only inside this `for in` block -

```
{% for order in all_orders %} 
    ... 
{% endfor %}
```

As you did here -

```
   {% if order.order_sent %}
       <img src="https://imgur.com/a/zXKjvAj"/>
   {% endif %}
```

If object doesn't exist in context when you trying to use it in django template, you'll get an empty string

For example

```
   {{ some_not_existing_value }}
```

won't display anything, but won't break anything either

Comment: Thank you for you reply. Can you tell me how to pass the form action to the views sent?

Comment: you can move form into your loop 

If you don't mind to have a lot of forms on your page. Just like here - https://pastebin.com/LpwyrM2c